# \copydoc command output in Doxygen is excluded from \brief content

Tags: documentation, javadoc, doxygen

I'd like to use \copydoc to include some values that may change inside a member's brief description.

Unfortunately, everything after the \copydoc command gets excluded from the \brief description and then mangled.

e.g.

```
/** 
* \class macro_num_apples_range
* 5-10
*/

/** \brief an apple tree with \copydoc macro_num_apples_range apples in it. 
*/
apple_tree;
```

Where macro_num_apples_range is a class I've made earlier in the file (with EXCLUDE_SYMBOLS = macro* in the Doxyfile, so that it won't actually appear in Doxygen's output) to act like a variable that can be easily updated.

The desired output of the above being: "an apple tree with 5-10 apples in it." placed in the brief description of the member.

The actual result of the above is that "an apple tree with" ends up in the brief documentation, and then the rest ends up in a mangled state in the detailed documentation like so: "apples in it. 5-10 apples in it."

Generally, I've noticed that very weird things happen if \copydoc is not invoked on its own line.

In fact, an almost-workaround is to do something like:

```
/** 
* \class macro_num_apples_range
* 5-10
*/

/** \brief an apple tree with 
*\copydoc macro_num_apples_range 
* apples in it. 
*/
apple_tree;
```

In which case the weird doubling of "apples in it." will not occur. However, /brief descriptions only take their content from a single-line comment, so this doesn't quite do the trick.

Am I missing something fundamental about how Doxygen commands work in general, maybe?

Comment: Didn't test it but would \copydetails be something for you.